# Cannot initiate session store since unable to parse (ERROR 500)

Tags: npm, npm-install, adonis.js

adonis application returns this error message when cloned the project and run after installing `npm install`, but the same project is working in another mac book pro. even i am using a mac book pro and it returns the following error. it says error 500.

```
Error
Cannot initiate session store since unable to parse `3b4204e91221f241deaad16ec6e4ddc0rs82L3YRb0FL72WnRgcJACuQ3Pur5KO5XigYeIuvLtuv+r27yI+dQXmZNbUUqX0URC5bzdBT1lnnZdZutBu4rVBPjvTKX00KR/RRsx9zjF0Zx2lqpSDdwJqUoGvJdM4YnJA3D6EK71GRVfpAeEprchMf5E0hdVEgnzVxV0wgqOg=`
```

Comment: Did you execute the command: `adonis key:generate`

Comment: yes. actually issue was solved, once i clear the cookies from site settings, it resolved itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was really unknown and once i clean cookies from site settings of the browser, it was fixed itself, also i recommend to test all the sites on Incognito mode,